# Using a loop to select multiple columns from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am trying to create a `DataFrame` that only has certain columns from a previously created dataframe using a loop.

I have the following dataframe:

```
      Time  Amount  Amount i=2  Amount i=3  Amount i=4
0    20      10          20          20          20
1    10       5          10          10          10
2    15      25          50          50          50
```

I am then trying to create a new data frame which has the following columns:
Time, Amount, Amount =2, Amount i=3 using a loop function. I understand that this can be solved relatively easily by just select each column, but this is part of a larger project that I can't do that for.

So far I have this:

```
for i in range (2,4):
    df1 = df[['Time','Amount','Amount i={}'.format(i)]]
```

But this only pulls out the 'Time' , 'Amount' & 'Amount i=3.

```
   Time  Amount  Amount i=3
0    20      10          20
1    10       5          10
2     5      25          50
```

Comment: I think it must be pulling only 'Time' , 'Amount' & 'Amount i=2. Can you recheck?

Comment: Sorry, have updated now, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this if you want to use a loop

```
df1 = df[['Time','Amount'] + ['Amount i={}'.format(i) for i in range(2,4)]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could advantageously use `filter` with a `regex`:

```
df1 = df.filter(regex='Time|Amount( i=[23])?$')
```

`'Time|Amount( i=[23])?$'` -> `Time`, or `Amount` (alone or optionally followed by  `=x` where x is 2 or 3)

output:

```
   Time  Amount  Amount i=2  Amount i=3
0    20      10          20          20
1    10       5          10          10
2    15      25          50          50
```